# Python. Filling DataFrame: code optimisation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have big dataset with around 4M rows. I need to clean it by regex and put into Pandas' DataFrame. Here is my code for that:

```
# 1) reading a text file with a dataset, where 4M rows
orgfile = open("good_dmoz.txt", "r")

# 2) create an empty dataframe
df0=pd.DataFrame(columns=['url'])

# 3) creating mask for cleaning data
regex = re.compile(r"(?<=\')(.*?)(?=\')")

# 4) clearing data and put into the dataframe
for line in orgfile:
    urls = regex.findall(line)
    df0.url = df0.append({"url": urls[0]}, ignore_index=True)
```

The code handles the task in a small fragment, but it takes **too long time** to process full data (4M rows). My question is: is it possible to optimize the code? By optimization, I mean to reduce the speed of code execution.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell us what are you doing with this code? Consider providing a sample input and outout data.

Comment: Can't optimise if I don't know what to optimise for. Good luck with solving your own problem.

Comment: So does every row has a url for sure? or should it be checked first? What makes your code very slow is `append`, you'll get a lot of speed up just by initializing `df0` with rows `df0=pandas.read_csv(orgfile).str.replace(regex,'')` You just have to negate the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments to the question. However, we all started from somewhere. Shokan, as others mention, the performance issue you experience is in parts due to the `append` and the `for`-loop. Try this:

**1. Create pandas dataframe from textfile, one column only, one line per row**

```
df_rawtext = pd.read_csv('good_dmoz.txt', header = None, names = ['raw_data'], sep = '\n')
```

**2. Test for presence of regex per row and filter:**

```
PATTERN = r"(?<=\')(.*?)(?=\')"
df_rawtext = df_rawtext.loc[df_rawtext.iloc[:,0].str.contains(PATTERN)]
```

**3. Extract pattern**

```
df_rawtext['URL'] = df_rawtext['raw_data'].str.extract(PATTERN, expand = False)
```

**Comment**

I do step 2 here, because step 3 will throw an error for lines without match.

```
ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups
```

If someone knows a better way, feel free to contribute. I am eager to learn.